# format_date not working as expected

Tags: theming, datetime

I'm using Drupal 7.38 and I'm trying to print the creation date of a node in 3 separate divs, to be able to format it appart, so I created the following on the node.tpl.php:

```
            <div class="fecha">
                <div class="mes"><?php print $date; ?></div>
                <div class="mes"><?php print format_date($node->created, 'custom' , 'M'); ?></div>
                <div class="dia"><?php print format_date($node->created, 'custom' , 't'); ?></div>
                <div class="año"><?php print format_date($node->created, 'custom' , 'Y'); ?></div>
            </div>
```

But, when I go to the result page I've got this:

MAR, 07/28/2015 - 16:20

JUL

31

2015

So, why is the day showing the incorrect date???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `d` for the day of the month. Using `t` php displays the number of days for the given month. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Never mind.  Those type of mistakes can happen to anyone. They are like the lost keys in front of you :)

Answer (score 0):

`t` isn't the correct value for [`format_date`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) when using the day. The custom option for `format_date` uses PHP's [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) syntax. As such `t` outputs the number of days in that month. What you want to use is `j` to list the day in that month.